# Using KVC in NSSortDescriptor

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor, key-value-coding

I need to sort a bunch of objects based on an integer that is stored in an `NSString`.

I know this is one solution and it works:

```
NSSortDescriptor *mySortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"from" ascending: YES comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2)
{
   if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue])
   {
       return (NSComparisonResult) NSOrderedDescending;
   }

   if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue])
   {
       return (NSComparisonResult) NSOrderedAscending;
   }

   return (NSComparisonResult) NSOrderedSame;
}];

self.myObjects = [[self.data allObjects] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: @[mySortDescriptor]];
```

My question is, why can't I use KVO for this, it looks much cleaner, eg like this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *mySortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"from.integerValue" ascending: YES];
```

And then pass that to my `NSFetchRequest`

With this code, 200 appears before 21.

Comment: Is that your actual code? It should be `sortDescriptorWithKey:@"from.integerValue"`.

Comment: (Side note: Accessing properties via a key path is "Key-Value Coding", not "Key-Value Observing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sort descriptor for a (SQLite based) Core Data fetch request can only use persistent attributes and a limited set of built-in selectors, but not Objective-C methods like 
`integerValue`.

In this case, it seems that the `integerValue` is just ignored, so that the `from` values
are sorted as *strings*, and not as *numbers*.

If you cannot change the attribute type to "Integer" (which would solve the problem as well)
then you can use a special selector as a workaround:

```
NSSortDescriptor *mySortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"from"
                                  ascending:YES
                                   selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
```

`localizedStandardCompare` is the "Finder-like sort" and sorts strings containing digits 
according to their numerical value.