# NSPredicate fetch - compare NSString as Int

Tags: nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have a basic understanding of predicates, but am stuck with this.

I have 2 Core Data Objects:

**Car and Service**

Each have a odometer property that is a `NSString`.

I want to exclude certain results by comparing the odometer readings of both. I want to compare as a `Int`, not as a `NSString`.

This will not work, but it should detail what I am trying to do

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%i > [serviceOdometer intValue])", [self.currentCar.odometer intValue]];
```

I have the current Car as an Int, but cannot get the fetched Service odometer as an int.

Comment: If you have an NSString that contains a decimal integer (and on other non-blank characters to confound things) then `intValue` or `integerValue` will return the number.  But I don't think you can include a method call in your predicate like that.  It might work with dot notation -- `serviceOdometer.intValue`.  (Not real familiar with predicates.)

Comment: yeah, still unable to get it to work. Dot notation fails, this might be a case where i have to use an array rather than a fetched results controller.

Comment: (On reviewing the predicate documentation I could not find anywhere where parens `()` are mentioned.  Are you sure you should have those?)

Comment: I have used them when grouping multiple statements, i.e. @"(ofCar == %@) AND (completedSer == 0) not sure if it changes anything but makes it a little cleaner to read. I think i will just create a transient property in my data model, and that will return an int of the string.

Comment: What you suggested should work re: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879286/nspredicate-how-to-treat-strings-as-numbers but its still comparing as strings

Comment: @Smick: The `intValue` in the fetch request is probably simply ignored. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197855/using-kvc-in-nssortdescriptor for a similar issue with `integerValue` in a (Core Data) sort descriptor.

Comment: @MartinR thanks for that. I want to exclude those results from the fetch so it needed to be in the predicate. And as there is no way to manually remove the items in a fetched results controller looks like I'll need to use an array. If only I could use the block method!! Which don't work for SQL .... any other ideas ??

Comment: Can't you change the attribute type to Number? That would be the correct solution.

Comment: I'll just stick to using an array for that TableView, but good to know restrictions of core data for future app designs.